# USB open accessory permissions through a service in android

Tags: android

Good day,

I have an application which connects my android device to an arduino unit through a service. I have managed to make the connection but it keeps asking me for permission to  use the accessory whenever I plug it in. Is there any way to bypass this permission? It works perfectly with an intent filter if I do it through an activity, I have tried applying the same intent in the service but it does not seem to work :/.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="blink.service"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityCreate">
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".StartupIntent" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service 
            android:name=".MainService"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED"
                android:resource="@xml/accessory_filter" />
        </service>
        <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"/>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Here is the code in my manifest.
Thanx

Answer (score 2):

To bypass permission you must make your app a system app. To make an app run as a system app you must place the apk in system/app folder. For doing that i first remounted the system drive as rw (read-write) using adb using the following code:

```
adb remount rw
push "apk path" /system/app
adb remount ro
```

Now reboot the system. Android will no longer ask for permission.